# Tracking freighter and charter planes between two specified airports

Tags: cargo, charter-operations

Is there a way to find the historical data of the freighter and charter planes between two airports

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Does [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11814/62) help?

Comment: How historical? With subscription flightradar24 offers flight history up to a year.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the tail numbers of the aircraft, you can go to FlightAware.Com and request flight history there. Even if they have not filed flight plans (highly unlikely if they are commercial flights), if they are equipped with ADS-B the odds are high they will be picked up by the system at some point during their flight.